# Flask CGI htaccess 404 not found

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, cgi

I'm trying to get a minimum flask app up and running on a shared server so I tried following the basic flask quickstart instructions with the CGI deployment instructions (python 3.8.2). That was giving me the error descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138090/python-cgi-with-flask-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563906/500-internal-server-error-received-when-trying-to-create-a-cgi-application-fr); I couldn't really figure out the solution but I tried a bunch of stuff and finally adding the `os` commands in `myapp.cgi` ensures that running `./myapp.cgi` doesn't error with the below code (I can't access `cgi-bin`, so I use `.htaccess` instead). However, when I go to my home directory, I am still getting a `404 not found` error.

myapp.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from hello import app
import os

os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = ''
os.environ['SERVER_PORT'] = '80'
os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Don't interfere with static files
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /u/a/b/user/public/html/myapp.cgi/$1 [L]
```

hello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

I tried removing the `$1` as some SO thread suggested, but that doesn't work. I'm also not altogether sure if my solution for the `myapp.cgi` is correct, as while it seems to be a common problem, I can't find a proper solution.

The shared server is also setup such that if there is no `index.html`, it will display the file structure, but that it's happening either - it's going straight to the `404` error page.

What could be the issues here? How would I ensure I can run the flask app on the shared server?

Answer (score 1):

You should add this code to your `.htaccess` file in order to parse the codes of Python:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Also you may change index priority to something like this if Flask you're using does not redirect:

```
DirectoryIndex index.py my_script.py test.php etc.extension
```

Comment: tried adding both onto the `.htaccess`. still getting `404`

Comment: When you open link like yoursite.com/script.py, does it work and open in the web browser? Or it shows you the plain code without being executed? Also check your files permissions are 0755.

Comment: Yes, the permissions are 0755. I get a `No such file or directory` error. It does load, but it goes to the 404 page.

Comment: stop your Flask project and write a simple .py file with only `print('hello')` to see if you can run a simple file on your host.

Comment: hmmm. that seems to be it. It's still giving me a 404 error for some reason if I try to access `*.py` but works for `*.html`. Let me look into that.

Comment: it's odd that you still get 404 error. Check your hosting settings and also see if any .php file works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221897/discussion-between-user760900-and-saeed).

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: Yes, it works for me as I'm now using this `.htaccess` rules in my website. Be sure your rules are executed before.